# How t multiplier is calculated from df and 95% confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval, t-test

> The appropriate t-multiplier for a 95% confidence interval for the
>   mean $\mu$ is t(0.025,14) = 2.15.

How to get this value `2.15`? Is there any formula ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is the 97.5%-quantile of the t-distribution with (in your case) 14 degrees of freedom.

In the figure the dashed line shows the value such that the yellow shaded area has size 0.975: the 97.5%-quantile is the value such that 97.5% of the probability mass is to the left of it and the rest to the right.

You may be wondering why the 97.5%-quantile and not the 95%-quantile: the standard confidence interval is a two-sided one in which you put $\alpha/2$ of the probability mass to the left and $\alpha/2$ to the right.

[image]

In `R`,

```r
> qt(.975,14)
[1] 2.144787
```

Plot produced in `R` using

```
xax <- seq(-4,4,by=.1)
plot(xax,dt(xax,14),type="l",xlab="test statistic",ylab="t-distribution with 14 d.f.") 
polygon(c(xax[1],seq(xax[1],qt(.975,14),by=.01),qt(.975,14)),c(0,dt(seq(xax[1],qt(.975,14),by=.01),14),0),col="lightyellow") 
abline(v=qt(.975,14),lty=2)
```

Comment: Here you have used qt function, what is it inside this function which calculates this value?

Comment: If $f(x,14)$ is the density of the t with 14 d.f., you need to solve $\int_{-\infty}^uf(x,14)dx=0.975$ for $u$. That is tricky analytically, though!